# My cells only update with a physical carriage return in the Formula Bar?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula based on other variables and data from multiple created worksheets.
My string text is correct. For example:
='Field Order 1009'!C7
But this is what I see in my cell AND in my Formula bar.
Only when I click in the formula bar and hit enter does the "formula" get the correct data.
sample of cell data after string is added to the cell. I did NOT hit enter in the bottom three cells

[image: 1]

.
Thank you for helping this old rookie :)

```
Sub NewTicket()
'Generate a New Field Order (FO)
'Field Orders are to become Field Change Orders - FCO
'Check if any Field Orders ("ticket" from the Sales Order Version of this) have been generated yet
'if no, use cell B1 as starting ticket number
'if yes, find the last empty cell in column A, move up one row, save the value, add one create the new ticket number
'
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim strFileName, workSheetName, newFormula As String
Dim currentTicket, ticket As Integer

Worksheets("FCO Log").Activate
Worksheets("FCO Log").Range("A9").Activate

Set currentTicket = ActiveCell

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
    Set currentTicket = Worksheets("FCO Log").Range("L2")
    ActiveCell.Value = currentTicket
    ticket = currentTicket
    
Else
    Do While ActiveCell.Value > 1
        LastTicket = ActiveCell.Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop
    ticket = LastTicket + 1
    ActiveCell.Value = ticket
    ' create the formula text to look up the FO Description in the newly created FO sheet
    'Set FormulaText = "='Field Order '!C7"
    'Application.StatusBar = FormulaText
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ' I tried some things here Column B, but then moved to the column K
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Select
    newFormula = ActiveCell.Value
    MsgBox ActiveCell.Value ' All the values shown look correct
    MsgBox newFormula       ' All the values shown look correct
    ' Copy the contents of this cell
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Select  ' Return to column B and paste the text formula now merged with the populated ticket number
    ' Paste the contents into this cell
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
   
    'Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}" This did not do anything. If I could get the ENTER in the formula bar...
    
End If

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)

workSheetName = "Field Order " & ticket

With ActiveSheet
   .Name = "Field Order " & ticket
   .Range("I5").Value = ticket
End With

Worksheets("FCO Log").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Of course I am certain this is a rudimentary fundamental flaw in my approach. Still. I appreciate the education. TY all!

Comment: how are the formulas entered? through code?

Comment: Under the "Formulas" tab of your excel ribbon, can you confirm the "Calculation Options" are set to "Automatic"?

Comment: Formulas string is calculated in cells but currently entered thru code

Comment: Yes. Calculations are automatic.. It is though each cell needs this one more step of a manual "enter". I can change other cells, navigate from cell to cell, even hit "enter" while on the cell itself, but until I go to the Formula bar and hit enter, it does not register and this needs to be done for every cell once. After that it updates automatically.

Comment: Looks like the cell is formatted as Text. But then it would stay as Text after hitting *Enter*. Are you using `.Formula` in VBA?

Comment: I did use the .Formula in other tests, but it did not work. It many not have worked for reasons other than the .Formula. I'll play some more. THX!

Comment: Looks like the cell was formatted as *Text* while entering the formula and was formatted e.g. as *General* afterward. Could you share the relevant code?

Comment: I've been trying so many things, let me clean up what has gotten me the closest and I'll share. TY.

Comment: This behavior will occur If the formulas are copied from a *String* array (e.g. an array created using the `Split` function). To solve this, declare the array as *Variant* if possible.

Comment: Edited base comment to show code. cells formatted as TEXT

Comment: I probably understand columns `B` and `K`. What is in cell `L2` and what is the significance of cell `A9` (is it supposed to be 1 i.e. the first ticket?)?

Comment: VBasic2008 - Vell L2 is the starting number for Field Orders for this particular project. There may be reasons why we want to start with one number or another, including having multiple leads or different buildings in a complex so even if people change, all tickets can easily be followed by number to a person, building, or just a section of the project. A9 is the FIRST cell the First ticket/Field Order number will be placed. I have spaces and header information above that for the log of the orders.

Answer (score 1):

### Getting Rid of `Select` and `Activate`

- Study [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999) to
  *"How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA"*.
- What you're experiencing is expected since you are copying the value from column `K`, a string representing the desired formula that you have generated using concatenation, by using `PasteSpecial`. You can easily do this manually and prove that it doesn't work.
- The way to go would have been something like e.g. `.Range("B2").Formula = .Range("K2").Value` but that would have raised another issue namely opening the *Update Values* dialog since the sheet that the formula refers to didn't exist at that time.
- Create a copy of your workbook before trying the code since there wasn't enough information to ensure the desired result.

```vb
Sub NewTicket()
' Generate a New Field Order (FO)
' Field Orders are to become Field Change Orders - FCO
' Check if any Field Orders ("ticket" from the Sales Order Version of this)
' have been generated yet
' *** I don't know what the above means but I modified the below.***
' If no, use the value in cell 'L2' as the starting ticket number
' and write it to cell 'A9'.
' If yes, find the last non-empty cell in column 'A', add one to its value
' and use it as the new ticket number and write it into the cell below.
    
    ' Reference the workbook so you don't end up with run-time errors
    ' when it is not the active one.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
     
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("FCO Log") ' qualify! i.e. 'wb.'
    
    Dim sNewRow As Long, NewTicketNumber As Long
    
    ' Determine the source new row and the new ticket number.
    With sws.Range("A9")
        Dim sLastRow As Long
        sLastRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row
        If sLastRow < .Row Then ' the first cell is not populated
            NewTicketNumber = sws.Range("L2").Value
            sNewRow = .Row ' first row
        Else ' the first cell is populated
            NewTicketNumber = sws.Cells(sLastRow, .Column).Value + 1
            sNewRow = sLastRow + 1 ' row below the last row
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Note that at this point nothing was modified: the workbook and
    ' source worksheet references were created and values were stored
    ' in 2 variables (3 if you count the now irrelevant 'sLastRow').
     
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     
    ' Destination
     
    ' Create and reference a copy of the template sheet, the destination sheet.
    wb.Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' before last
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count - 1) ' before last
    ' or:
    'wb.Sheets("Template").Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' last
    'Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count) ' last

    ' Generate the destination sheet name.
    Dim dwsName As String: dwsName = "Field Order " & NewTicketNumber
    
    ' Rename and write the new ticket number to the destination sheet.
    With dws
        .Name = dwsName
        .Range("I5").Value = NewTicketNumber
    End With
    
    ' Source
    
    ' Write the new ticket number to the source sheet (could have been
    ' in the code above) and only now, when the destination sheet
    ' already exists, write the formula (no need for the helper column 'K'!?).
    With sws
        .Cells(sNewRow, "A").Value = NewTicketNumber
        .Cells(sNewRow, "B").Formula = "='" & dwsName & "'!C7"
    End With
    
    ' Cosmetics: don't wanna look at the newly created destination sheet
    ' but the source sheet.
    sws.Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Ticket " & NewTicketNumber & " created.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Going there right after this next meeting of mine. I Sincerely and greatly appreciate your engagement with me!!!